# How to get Application() class on Test classes

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

I am trying to get the Application() class on a Test class, the thing is that I am unable, I thought that by using `@Mock private lateinit var app: Application` but it did not worked, I have been searching by a while and still cannot find how to

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer on a video, the simplest way to do so is this way, hope and helps someone in the future

```
context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```